# Difference in datetime stamps impala

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

I want a query that shows a time difference in months or days in Impala

How can I do this?

start 2017-11-29 19:45:00 - end 2018-11-29 21:30:00

I know that month_between and datediff shows the month of datediff but how do I make it so it also takes the year into count when counting the days / months?

For the above example, I want to to display either

month_between - 12.2 months - equivalent to the month calculation of the timestamp - might be a little off cause I did it by hand / 30 days

days_between - 366 days

Comment: They always takes year into account. For example, datediff and months between between 1-jan 2020 and 1-jan 2021 will be 365 and 12 recpectively. Did you test them?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you tried `DATEDIFF` or not , but it already gives you the dates difference in days :

```
select datediff(endddaate, startdate)
from tablename
```